# Search in text file using php

Tags: php, regex, search, text

I'm trying to find "hello" and get all the phrases/sentences, which are in between "----"

```
//in my text file 
$txt="
----hello, how are you----
----how are you,hello, how are you----
----how are you hello, how are you----
----hello how are you , how are you----
----how are you , how are you----

"
```

How can I get all the lines between ---- if `hello` word is in it?

my code

```
$re = '/(?=.*hello)(----.+?----)/m';
$fh = fopen('ara.txt', 'r') or die($php_errormsg); 
while (!feof($fn)) { 
$line = fgets($fn, 4096);

preg_match_all($re, $line, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
}
```

Comment: How about [`preg_grep('~\bhello\b~i', explode("----", $txt))`](https://eval.in/1111834)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If our strings all have `----`, we would simply use this expression:

```
(?=.*hello).*
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?=.*hello).*/m';
$str = '----hello, how are you----
----how are you,hello, how are you----
----how are you hello, how are you----
----hello how are you , how are you----
----how are you , how are you----
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/hCcUN0/1/)

If not, and we have to validate `----`, we would expand our expression to:

```
(?=.*hello)(----.+?----)
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?=.*hello)(----.+?----)/m';
$str = '----hello, how are you----
----how are you,hello, how are you----
----how are you hello, how are you----
----hello how are you , how are you----
----how are you , how are you----
---hello how are you , how are you---
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/HUzfc4/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired and you wish to modify it, please visit this link at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HUzfc4/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

And our code might look like:

```
$re = '/(?=.*hello)(----.+?----)/m';
$fh = fopen('/path/to/our/file/ara.txt', 'r') or die($php_errormsg);
while (!feof($fh)) {
    $line = fgets($fh, 4096);
    preg_match_all($re, $line, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Comment: thank you, now I just try to open my txt file but its not working . my code in my question

Answer (score 1):

Try `preg_match_all` function

```
    //in my text file
    $txt = "
----hello, how are you----
----how are you,hello, how are you----
----how are you hello, how are you----
----hello how are you , how are you----
----how are you , how are you----";

    $pattern = "/[^\\n]*hello[^\\n]*/";
    preg_match_all($pattern,$txt, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    $final = [];
    foreach($matches[0]??[] as $match){
        $final[] = str_replace('----','',$match[0]);
    }
    print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its easier like this

```
$txt="
----hello, how are you----
----how are you,hello, how are you----
----how are you hello, how are you----
----hello how are you , how are you----
----how are you , how are you----

";

preg_match_all('/\-\-\-\-(.*hello.*)\-\-\-\-/', $txt, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);

Array ( [0] => hello, how are you [1] => how are you,hello, how are you [2] => how are you hello, how are you [3] => hello how are you , how are you )
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a positive lookahead `(?=.*hello` to assert if what follows is hello.

You could use a capturing group with a non greedy match `.*?` to prevent over matching and place `hello` between word boundaries `\b`:

```
----(.*?\bhello\b.*?)----
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fj9jgg/1)

Your values will be in the first capturing group.